# Attribute Error

Tags: python, attributeerror

I've opened a command prompt to see why the piece of code is not working and it says:

AttributeError: 'module' objec has no attribute 'randint'

```
import random

print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 50')

number = random.randint(1, 50)
guess = int(input('Can you guess what it is: '))

while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
        print('Lower...')

    else:
        print('higher...')

    guess = int(input('Can you guess what it is: '))


print('Correct!')

input('\n\nEnter.')
```

Comment: It seems that you have another module named random. If so, you must rename it to different name in order to avoid namespace issues

Comment: Maybe you've named your python file random.py ?

Comment: Please give us the complete and real traceback and not prosaic text.

Comment: the code works fine for me , maybe your file name is random.py ? or you have another module called random ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a script called `random.py` in the current directory (probably this script).  Rename it to something else, because it's shadowing the standard `import random`.